# Empty array in absence of data when displaying as JSON in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json result

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "ABQ-PHX",
    "series": [
      {
        "item": {
          "item_id": 1,
          "name": "a1",
          "start": "03-12-2013,16:29",
          "end": "11-12-2013,16:29"
        }
      },
      {
        "item": {
          "item_id": 3,
          "name": "a2",
          "start": "10-12-2013,16:38",
          "end": "30-12-2013,16:38"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "BNA-RDU"
  }
]
```

For "id":2,there is no series data in the database but I need the empty series array to be included

```
   [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "ABQ-PHX",
        "series": [
          {
            "item": {
              "item_id": 1,
              "name": "a1",
              "start": "03-12-2013,16:29",
              "end": "11-12-2013,16:29"
            }
          },
          {
            "item": {
              "item_id": 3,
              "name": "a2",
              "start": "10-12-2013,16:38",
              "end": "30-12-2013,16:38"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "BNA-RDU",
        "series":[]
      }
    ]
```

Is there a way to bring an empty array even when data is not present?
I am doing this in javascript and stringify the above result

Please help

Comment: the s/m is not aware of your data structure , so it has no idea about  'series' field you can check after converting it to object and whether obj.series is 'undefined'

Comment: you can set it as [] when you first time use it: "obj.series=obj.series || []", if series is null or undefined, it will set as []. Not sure if this is what you want.